# Creating a table using VBA for Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I managed code to create a group of tables based off of .csv files inside of a folder.
I want each of them to be a separate table so most of the concatenation posts weren't for me.

```vb
Public Function importExcelSheets(Directory As String) As Long

 On Error Resume Next

 Dim strDir As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim I As Long
 Dim N As Long
 Dim FSO As Object, MyFile As Object
 Dim FileName As String, Arr As Variant
 Dim Content As String
 Dim objStreamIn
 Dim objStreamOut
 
 'Prepare Table names-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 FileName = "path/to/table/names.txt"
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
 Arr = Split(MyFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
 
 'Verify Directory and pull a file------------------------------------------------------------------------
 If Left(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
     strDir = Directory & "\"
 Else
     strDir = Directory
 End If
 strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")

 'Fill Tables----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 I = UBound(Arr) - 1
 While strFile <> ""
     strFile = strDir & strFile
     Set objStreamIn = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     Set objStreamOut = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStreamIn.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStreamOut.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStreamIn.Open
    objStreamOut.Open
    objStreamIn.LoadFromFile (strFile)
    objStreamOut.Open

    N = 1
    While Not objStreamIn.EOS
        Content = objStreamIn.ReadText(-2)
        If N = 1 Then
            Content = Replace(Content, "/", vbNullString, , 1)
            objStreamOut.WriteText Content & vbCrLf
        Else
            objStreamOut.WriteText Content & vbCrLf
        End If
        N = N + 1
    Wend

    objStreamOut.SaveToFile strFile, 2
    objStreamIn.Close
    objStreamOut.Close
    Set objStreamIn = Nothing
    Set objStreamOut = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferText _
        TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
        TableName:=Arr(I), _
        FileName:=strFile, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        CodePage:=65001
     strFile = Dir()
     I = I - 1
 Wend
 importExcelSheets = I
End Function
```

It works until the last section where I use TransferText to create the table.
It will get different results based on a few things I've tried:

1. Running the script after commenting out the entire objStream section gives me the data and table names, but the headers are [empty], "F2", "F3", ... "F27".
   I suspected it was because there was a forward slash in the first column header, so I put in the `Replace()` to remove it.
2. Running the script as in above gives me an empty table.
   I now suspect that the encoding header of the file is the reason for this.
3. Running the script after changing `objStreamOut.Charset = "utf-8"` to `objStreamOut.Charset = "us-ascii"` and updating the CodePage to 20127 gives me an empty table with black diamond question marks for a column header.

I want to blame the encoding characters but it ran one time almost flawlessly with the utf-8 encoding and CodePage 65001. Is there another way around this?

[Here is the Byte Order Mark of the file showing the UTF-8 Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KJMR.png)

Edit: changed CodeType to CodePage and added vbCrLf to append to Content
Edit: Included picture of Hex for files showing UTF-8 offest

Comment: When you say "CodeType" do you mean "CodePage"? Use of ADODB.Stream is new to me. I have seen FileSystemObject to open/write text files and text file Input/Print. I've never had to specify Charset and CodePage. You confirmed the Output file has data? I tested your code. The text file is modified to remove the / character but also there are no line returns, just one long line. No table is created.

Comment: I modified code to concatenate vbCrLf: `Content & vbCrLf`. Instead of creating a text file of table names to fill array, I just commented out the array code and used a fixed string for table name. Table is created with data. Apparently your array is correctly populated because you say tables are created, just not with data.

Comment: Yes sorry. I updated CodeType to be CodePage as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from Comments it looks like I got it to work after fixing the vbCrLf problem. I switched the objStreamOut charset to us-ascii and changed the CodePage to 20127 to reflect that as well. I now have headers, table names, and data working normally. Here is the final code:

```
Public Function importExcelSheets(Directory As String) As Long
On Error Resume Next
 Dim strDir As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim I As Long
 Dim N As Long
 Dim FSO As Object, MyFile As Object
 Dim FileName As String, Arr As Variant
 Dim Content As String
 Dim objStreamIn
 Dim objStreamOut
 
 'Prepare Table names-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 FileName = "path/to/table/names.txt"
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
 Arr = Split(MyFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
 
 'Verify Directory and pull a file------------------------------------------------------------------------
 If Left(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
     strDir = Directory & "\"
 Else
     strDir = Directory
 End If
 strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")

 'Fill Tables----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 I = UBound(Arr) - 1
 While strFile <> ""
     strFile = strDir & strFile
     Set objStreamIn = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     Set objStreamOut = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStreamIn.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStreamOut.Charset = "us-ascii"
    objStreamIn.Open
    objStreamOut.Open
    objStreamIn.LoadFromFile (strFile)
    objStreamOut.Open

    N = 1
    While Not objStreamIn.EOS
        Content = objStreamIn.ReadText(-2)
        If N = 1 Then
            Content = Replace(Content, "/", vbNullString, , 1)
            objStreamOut.WriteText Content & vbCrLf
        Else
            objStreamOut.WriteText Content & vbCrLf
        End If
        N = N + 1
    Wend

    objStreamOut.SaveToFile strFile, 2
    objStreamIn.Close
    objStreamOut.Close
    Set objStreamIn = Nothing
    Set objStreamOut = Nothing
     DoCmd.TransferText _
        TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
        TableName:=Arr(I), _
        FileName:=strFile, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        CodePage:=20127
     strFile = Dir()
     I = I - 1
 Wend
 importExcelSheets = I
End Function
```

Still not entirely sure why VBA was not getting the correct data when I used utf-8 and 65001 for CodeType and works now for us-ascii. This will work for me however.

Comment: Odd, because I did not have to change Charset and CodePage. Is this a split db and backend is also Access?

Comment: I'm not sure. It just wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: You don't know if db is split with Access backend?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what that means

Comment: It means one file holds all tables and data (backend) and another file links to backend and holds queries/forms/reports/code for GUI (frontend).

Comment: I don't think so. I just run the VBA script and it pulls all the data from every csv in one folder and creates all the tables into one Access file. I don't have any further queries, or reports. The one form holds the button that I press to initiate the VBA but It is all in one Access File

Comment: Can't explain why we got different behaviors.